# Example of EJB3 Mybatis and CMT

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0, ibatis, mybatis

Somebody knows an example with EJB3 and Mybatis where the container controls the transaction, the only part of code I founded was:

SQLMapConfig.xml

---

```
<transactionManager type="EXTERNAL">
    <property name="SetAutoCommitAllowed" value="false"/>
    <dataSource type="JNDI">
        <property name="DataSource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sisds"/>
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```

But I have many questions, for example,

1. When the container make the commit?
2. When the container release the session to the pool?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The container commits the transaction based on how your EJBs are configured. If you are using bean managed transactions, then you have to manage the `UserTransaction` yourself.

Regardless, you have to manage the MyBatis SqlSession yourself. Setting the tx type to `EXTERNAL` (`MANAGED` in Mybatis 3), simply means that MyBatis never calls commit on the DB connection - it relies on the container to commit.